# How do I Change default action for hard drive folder under My Computer in Widows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

I mean, how do I change the "Open As..." to point another program when I double click the Hard Drive (C:)

Comment: I've googled for it but i couldn't find anything...

Comment: Which program do you want to open C:? 99% of Windows users want to use Explorer.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to open with any other executable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Autorun.inf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf#A_simple_example) Like on CDs/DVDs?

I usually use this to change the Icon of a flash drive. but there is an option called `OPEN=` that will launch an executable.